# Show that a set of all limit points of subsequences is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and consider the set:
    $$E:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}, \text{there exists a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $x$.}\}$$
Show that $E$ is closed.

I can think about three situations, two of which are easy to prove. 
The first, $E$ is empty. The second, $E$ has one element. The third, $E$ has more than one element. I'm struggling to prove the third.

I think that I might be misunderstanding what the set E is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x\not\in E$, there must be an open set $U$ with no element of $(x_n)$ contained in $U$.  That is, $U\cap (x_n)=\emptyset$.  Hence $U\cap E=\emptyset$.  Hence $\Bbb R\setminus E$ is open.

Comment: Thanks. Why does $U$ must exist?

Comment: Well, if not then for every $U_n=(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n)$, we have an element $a_n$ of $(x_n)$ with $a_n\in U_n$.  So $(a_n)$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ with $a_n\to x$.  So $x\in E\,\Rightarrow \Leftarrow $.

Comment: And I'm not entirely clear on why $U$ is open..

Comment: There has to be at least one such open $U$,  or else we arrive at the contradiction outlined above.